# Reference postgresql query column in other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given I have table with some data... I have a query which is used to retrieve a data with complex case clause...

```
 SELECT row_number() over (...) as num, ... as field 1, 
    case ... as field2 
    FROM ...
```

Now I would like to add more complex logic, like

```
 SELECT row_number() over (...) as num, ... as field 1, 
    field2 * num as field2 
    FROM ...
```

Basically, if I type `row_num + 1 as field2` Postgres returns me

ERROR: column "row_num" does not exist

How I can reference on field of query inside this query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make a outer table and select field 2 in that table

```
Select *, num+1 as field2
from
(
   SELECT row_number() over (...) as num, ... as field1 FROM ...
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT row_number() over (...) as num,
       1 + row_number() over (...) as field2,
       ... as field3,
  FROM ...
```